# Inconsistency between sample median and theoretical median for skewed normal using rsnorm in fGarch

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, skew-normal-distribution

I am using the `rsnorm` function within the R `fGarch` package to generate random samples from a skewed normal distribution. However, the median of the resulting simulation is inconsistent with the output of the quantile function `qsnorm`.

```
> median(rsnorm(n=100e3,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5))  # Median of random sample
[1] -0.1159801
> qsnorm(p=0.5,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5)  # Median from quantile function  
[1] -0.5941504
```

The code snippet above shows that the median of the random sample is nearly 0.48 different from the theoretical median. The upper and lower quartiles match to within 0.01. What am I doing wrong? Are the simulated numbers or the quantile function incorrect?

Comment: Just a thought - you might want to compare your results with `rsn` and `qsn` from the `sn` package.

Comment: Thanks Silverfish -- I've done as you suggest and the functions from the `sn` package don't have this problem. I also experimented with using the `skewt` package, and setting the degrees of freedom parameter to the skewed T distribution very high (to approximate a normal) ... this also worked, after allowing for the differing parameterisation in `skewt`. I will submit a bug report to the maintainer of the `fGarch` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been using the default values of `mean`, `sd` and `xi`.

```
library(fGarch)
median(rsnorm(n=100e3,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5))  # Median of random sample
qsnorm(p=0.5,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5)  # Median from quantile function
```

Gave your output:

```
> median(rsnorm(n=100e3,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5))  # Median of random sample
[1] -0.1159801
> qsnorm(p=0.5,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5)  # Median from quantile function  
[1] -0.5941504
```

Let's check the cumulative distribution functions:

```
psnorm(-0.1159801,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5) # Median of random sample, comes out close enough
[1] 0.5006487

psnorm(-0.5941504,mean=0,sd=1,xi=1.5) # From the quantile function, expect 0.5 exactly
[1] 0.3076923
```

Well that's odd. Is something up with the quantile function? This is even odder:

```
qsnorm(p = seq(from = 0.45, to = 0.55, by = 0.01), mean=0, sd=1, xi=1.5)
 [1] -0.22682722 -0.19701387 -0.16617075 -0.13413508 -0.10071017 -0.59415042
 [7] -0.09171829 -0.06558985 -0.03925899 -0.01271222  0.01406462
```

So `qsnorm(p = 0.5)` does not seem consistent with nearby quantiles. What if we change `mean`, `sd` and `xi` from their default values?

```
qsnorm(p = seq(from = 0.45, to = 0.55, by = 0.01), mean=2, sd=0.5, xi=1.2)
 [1] 1.907266 1.919828 1.932450 1.945145 1.957927 1.857169
 [7] 1.982745 1.995506 2.008334 2.021235 2.034215
```

Less conspicuous this time, but the ouput of `qsnorm(p = 0.5, mean=2, sd=0.5, xi=1.2)` is `1.857169` and once again is inconsistent with nearby quantiles.

EDIT: but both "medians" are conspicuous on a plot.

```
p <- seq(from = 0.45, to = 0.55, by = 0.01)
plot(p, qsnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1, xi = 1.5)) # default parameters
```

[image: Graph of qsnorm with default parameters]

```
plot(p, qsnorm(p, mean = 2, sd = 0.5, xi = 1.2)) # alternative parameters
```

[image: Graph of qsnorm with alternative parameters]

This looks to me like an issue with `qsnorm` and I can't see anything in the documentation for it. For comparison, `qnorm` does exactly what you might expect for the normal distribution.

```
qnorm(p = seq(from = 0.45, to = 0.55, by = 0.01), mean=0, sd=1)
 [1] -0.12566135 -0.10043372 -0.07526986 -0.05015358 -0.02506891
 [6]  0.00000000  0.02506891  0.05015358  0.07526986  0.10043372
[11]  0.12566135

plot(p, qnorm(p, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

[image: Graph of pnorm]

EDIT: just in case this changes in future versions I ought to include:

```
> packageVersion("fGarch")
[1] ‘3010.82’
```